# Cobertura analysis reporting "[ERROR] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings."

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, coverage, maven, sonarqube

Cobertura is reporting that there are multiple SLF4J bindings in the classpath, actually both related to different versions of the logback-classic artifact:

```
[ERROR] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.13/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

But I have been able to find the origin of the older version (1.0.13), as it doesn't appear in the dependency tree from the corresponding maven goal:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building inbound 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ inbound ---
[INFO] cl.waypoint:inbound:jar:0.0.1
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- uk.co.jemos.podam:podam:jar:7.1.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:test
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO]    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO]    |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.788 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-19T12:25:47-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/227M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Could this logback come from the Cobertura plugin itself and, then it's a plugin bug? What additional info should I provide? What could wrong?

- Jenkins: ver 2.96
- SonarQube: Version 6.7 (build 33306)
- Cobertura Plugin in Jenkins: 2.1.1
- Cobertura Plugin in SonarQube: 1.9.1
- cobertura-maven-plugin: 2.7